# Trying to write function trying to extract number from a string, but it is returning unrelated number

Tags: c++, pointers, debugging, text-extraction

I am tring to write a function that extract number from a string stored in char array. E.g. input: "141923adsfab321221.222", my function should return the 141923 and 321221.222. Below is what i have come up so far, it runs and compiles but it spits out totally unrelated numbers like 48 49 50 51 etc no matter how i change the input. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
double GetDoubleFromString(char * str){
    static char * start;
    //starting point of the search
    if(str)
        start=str;
    //check if str is empty
    for (;*start&&!strchr("0123456789.",*start);++start);
    //jump thru chars that are not num related
    if (*start=='\0'){
        return -1;
    // check if at the end of the string
    }
    char *q=start;
    //mark the position of the start of a number
    for (;*start&&strchr("0123456789.",*start);++start);
    //jump thru chars that are num related
    if (*start){
        *start='\0';
        ++start;
    //as *start rest at a non num related char, mutate it to \0 and push forward
    }
    return *q;
    //I tried return (double) *q; but that does not work either and in the same way
}

int main(){
    char line[300];
    while(cin.getline(line,280)) {
        double n;
        n = GetDoubleFromString(line);
        while( n > 0) {
            cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << n << endl;
            n = GetDoubleFromString(NULL);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You function returnes ASCII codes of digits. You missed appropriate arithmetic with digits.

Comment: @S.M. That explains the 48 49 50 51........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your digit separation code is right, but you're missing the critical step of converting a character array `['1', '4', '1', '9', '2', '3', '\0']` into a double `141923`. The standard library has the function [`std::atof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atof) designed specifically for this purpose.

You'd just use it at the return like so:

```
return std::atof(q);
```

Comment: And it works! Thank you